# Contact me form doesn't want to work - using smtpjs.com

Tags: javascript, smtp

I'm new to smtp and could use some help. My code is below, I'm using https://smtpjs.com as a free alternative to help send requests to my smtp server.

````
  Email.send({
    SecureToken: "token",
    Password: "password",
    To: "connorwitmer34@gmail.com",
    From: fields.email,
    Subject: `${fields.subject} - ${fields.phone}`,
    Body: fields.message,
  }).then((message) => alert(message)); 

```
````

It can be assumed that the fields object is working fine.

The error I am getting when using any email besides my own is `Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: Envelope FROM 'test@gmail.com' email address not allowed.` Please note that this is the "sender" address, not the address I want it sent to. It seems to work fine when I use my personal email.

Could this be some sort of weird safeguard against spam? If so, how do I combat this?

Comment: form `test@gmail.com`? unlikely you own `gmail.com` - when using a secure token, the token is "locked" to a single domain - i.e. **your domain** - so, you can only send "from" that domain that is set up in the token - re-reading the docs, I may be WRONG though :p

Comment: So when a user inputs their email into the "Email field", I can't just use the email that they use? This is making me question how everyone else makes their contact forms then.

*I've just added a new email to verified senders, and it works fine when using that email. This begs the question to me, can I turn this verification off?

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been fixed. I remedied my "non-verified email" issue but setting both the to AND from fields to my email, and then just adding the users email to the message body. Apparently several months back were abusing a feature, and Google's security policy was updated to prevent spam/hackers.